# SQL - Server always encrypted not workings with applicationpoolidentity

Tags: sql-server

I have a web application that read and write from/to database and I use with always encrypted.

When I tried my web application in my local device(where I developed the site) it's work perfect but when I created web site in the server it's can't read from the database because my application doesn't found the CEK(the public key cert).

In the server I created a new database and do the always encrypted, and add the applicationpoolidentity to my database with the following steps:

- Add login account IIS APPPOOL\name applicationpoolidentity.
- Add the login as user in the relevant database.

I search a lot for solution but nothing work.

For example:

- Create new windows user connect to database with SQL Server in
  Single-User Mode : I saw that solution will be problematic.
- Add name application pool identity as login windows auth in the
  SQL-Server but not working. Who can i connect with application pool
  identity as login to SQL-Server?

I gave up, I need help :)

Comment: Are IIS and SQL Server on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after many searches for a soulotion I found one.

Untill now I created always with Current User Certificate Stores and because of that I can't use with the cert in all users.
So I generate new certificate in Local Machine Certificate Stores [image]

and add the application pool identity to the cert permissions with the following steps:

- run mmc.
- Click Certificates -> right click on the specific cert -> all task -> manage private key -> click add -> enter the name application pool identity to the textbox -> click ok -> check v on read permission and click ok.
  [image]

Now the always encrypted work perfect.